# Creating a file in c# with the present date as its name

Tags: c#

I have to create a log file and the log file name should be "11/09/2015 log.txt"

So whenever the application is executed  the date should get updated along with the name of the file.

How can I do this.

Comment: You can have a look at `log4net` or `entlib log handler`

Comment: Any effort so far? It doesn't look like a hard problem to solve IMHO..

Comment: Using '/' is mistake, too many OSes will treat it as folder delimeters; better to use '-'.

Comment: No...no idea regarding this

Comment: You can't have `/` in a filename, so you'll need to change the format to start with. I'd recommend `yyyy-MM-dd` - no problematic characters, and the sort order ends up being chronological.

Comment: Ignore the fact that you're trying to use the result as a filename - what you're trying to do is take a `DateTime` and format it in a particular way. I suggest you research that.

Comment: What happens if the app runs into the next day.  Should it change the log file or not?

Comment: The name of the log file should show the start date and time of the application.

Answer (score 1):

Special characters such as `\/:"?<>|` are not allowed in file names. but you can create a file with current date as it's name in following way:

```
   string filename=DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy");   
   File.Create(@"D:\"  +filename +".txt");
```

If you want to rename the file in next application run means so like this:

```
 File.Move("oldFilepath", filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to write logs, take a look at some logs libraries. I would go for [NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target). If you need a date in a file name, read about [File target](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target). This is how it could look:

```xml
  <targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="logs/log_${shortdate}.txt" />
  </targets>
```

Also, as Richard mentioned, do not use `/` in file names…